# If $f(x)^2>f(x+dx)f(x-dx)$, then $f(x+dx)f(x-dx)>f(x+adx)f(x-adx)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Supose that $f(x)$ is continuous and monotonic. Assume that, for all $x$, small $dx$ and $a>1$, $f(x)^2>f(x+dx)f(x-dx)$.
>
> Show that $f(x+dx)f(x-dx)>f(x+adx)f(x-adx)$.

1. I have tried multiple examples in Mathematica and I believe that the proposition is true. If it is true, I'd be grateful to see a proof. If it is not true, I'd be grateful to see a counter example.
2. This is related to a question I posted yesterday ([Show that $erfc[\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}]erfc[\frac{y-c}{b\sqrt{2}}]<erfc[\frac{x-c}{b\sqrt{2}}]erfc[\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2913509/426018)) and for which I have not figured out the solution yet. If the proposition in this post is true, then the proposition in the other post should follow. In this case, I will update the old post to provide the final answer (I post this question in a new post because it is very different from the initial one).

Any solution/idea will be highly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to be much more careful with your statement of the conditions! Your 'small $dx$' is too vague.

Comment: Thank you TonyK! I am not really experienced with math. My interpretation of $dx$ is the one that we typically use when we talk about derivatives. But you made me realize that I don't even know how to define it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The statement is not true**,  a counter example:

> $f(x)=erfc(x)+1$ (one can do a Taylor expansion to see that the initial condition holds for "small" $dx$), $x=1$, $dx=0.001$ and $a=100$. Then:
>
> $f(x)^2=1.339341$
>
> $f(x+dx)f(x-dx)=1.33934$
>
> $f(x+adx)f(x-adx)=1.34722$